# Как в Linux задать перемнную окружения для всех пользователей?

Tags: linux, bash, astra-linux, .bashrc, переменные-среды

Возникла необходимость в Atsra Linux задать переменную окружения для всех пользователей в системе.

Вроде как это должно задаваться через /etc/environment. Это работает для всех пользователей, кроме рута.

Как сделать так, чтобы рут тоже получал переменную из того же места, что и остальные пользователи? Возможно, надо прописать куда-то в другое место?  Хотелось бы иметь единое решение для всех пользователей, а не прописывать каждому дополнительно что-то в bashrc.

Comment: В обычных линуксах /etc/profile вроде бы работает для всех юзеров.  Как с этим обстоит дело в Atsra Linux (и прочих sra-линуксах), не знаю

Comment: /etc/profile не работает для рута в дебиане

Comment: Вот [тут](https://wiki.astralinux.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=190913831) все написано